# ¿Cómo cambiar contraseña de usuario desde el admin de Django 2.1?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, contraseña

Tengo un super usuario para acceder al admin de Django, lo que quiero es cambiarles la contraseña a los usuarios comunes para lo cual sigo las instrucciones del admin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> "Las contraseñas no se almacenan en texto plano, así que no hay manera
>   de ver la contraseña del usuario, pero se puede cambiar la contraseña
>   mediante *este formulario*."

Pero cuando le doy click al enlace sugerido me da este mensaje:

> 'Usuario con ID "`2/change/password`" no existe. ¿Fue quizá eliminado?'.

Es como si al ID del usuario le hubiera concatenado el resto de la URL (`/change/password`) y recién haya realizado la búsqueda del registro por lo que genera el error y no me muestra el formulario para cambiar la contraseña.

¿Quizá hay alguna configuración que se debe hacer en el archivo `settings.py` para habilitar dicha función?

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia, pero no era lo que buscaba, logre encontrar la solución en https://pypi.org/project/django-admin-reset/ el cual me generó automáticamente el enlace y formulario de cambio de contraseña dentro del administrador de django.

Answer (score 1):

usa esto en el shell de django

`manage.py changepassword <username>`

ó también puedes usar esto:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='john')
>>> u.set_password('new password')
>>> u.save()
```

Comment: Hola Jeanpierre, ¿qué es lo que hacen los comandos/snippets indicados? ¿cómo solucionarían el problema?

Answer (score -2):

En el `settings.py`, cuando ocupo `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-mx'` me pasa lo mismo pero con `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'`, no.

Cuando configuro `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-mx'`, se genera la seguiente ruta:

`/admin/appusr/user/1/change/password/`

cuando en realidad la ruta correcta es:

`/admin/appusr/user/1/password/`

Comment: Si bien ese código podría resolver el problema, es mejor explicar por qué lo haría